# JAX-WS generates unexpected element names for @WebParam

Tags: jboss, wsdl, tomcat7, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I'm stuck with a curious behaviour of `JAX-WS 2.2.10`.

I generated all java sources with `wsimport` using the maven plugin.
So far, the sources are looking good.
The deployed service implementation runs on a Tomcat 7 with Java 1.7.

My problem is:
I want to use these sources also for my service client.
But the communication with the service failes because the JAX-WS runtime expects other XML elements for the SOAP message.

Comparing the generated WSDL with the original WSDL and the annotations shows: JAX-WS on the server side generated custom names and **does not** use the defined names `@WebParam(name="...")` or `@WebResult(name="...")` but the client does!

Finally there are different message element names on both sides and this results in a Exception (`Cannot find dispatch method...`).

Can I control the behaviour of the WSDL generation on the server?
JAXB should use the given annotion or not?

Thanks in advance

**Edit, 2015-10-12**

Now I tried to generate new client sources based on the runtime generated WSDL of my server.
The result are several Exceptions during the maven task: `Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class`

Crazy. The framework creates a XML structure which could not be used by the framework.

**Edit, 2015-11-30**

This is my original WSDL definition which is the source for JAX-WS code generation:

```
<message name="checkServiceRequest">
  <part name="checkServiceRequestPart" element="tns:CheckServiceRequest" />
</message>
```

The generated java code is annotated with this snippet:

```
@WebParam(name = "CheckServiceRequest", 
  targetNamespace = "http://my.name.space", 
  partName = "checkServiceRequestPart")
```

The following WSDL snippet has been generated by JAX-WS runtime on **JBoss EAP 6.3.0**:

```
<message name="checkService">
  <part element="tns:CheckServiceRequest" name="checkServiceRequestPart"></part>
</message>
```

*The message name is different, but the part attributes are equal to the given annotations.*

The following WSDL snippet has been generated by JAX-WS runtime on **Tomcat** and **WebLogic 12.1.3**:

```
<message name="checkService">
  <part name="checkService" element="tns:checkService"/>
</message>
```

*The part attributes are different to the given annotations. Thus the client, which is using the annotations correctly, will send an unmatchable method call.*

**The differences**

For my development and WebLogic runtime uses the Oracle implementation of the mtro project:

```
Specification-Title:        The Java API for XML Web Services
Specification-Version:      2.2
Implementation-Title:       JAX-WS Implementation
Implementation-Vendor:      Sun Microsystems Inc
Implementation-Version:     2.2.10
Build-Version:              JAX-WS RI 2.2.10
```

JBoss has it's own implementation:

```
Specification-Title:        JSR-000224: Java(TM) API for XML-Based Web Services
Specification-Version:      2.2
Implementation-Title:       Java(TM) API for XML-Based Web Services 2.2
Implementation-Vendor:      JBoss by Red Hat
Implementation-Version:     2.0.2.Final-redhat-1
Bundle-Version:             2.0.2.Final-redhat-1
```

Comment: **2015-11-05**
I didn't pursue this issue so far, because we switches to an JavaEE app server instead of the Tomcat.

Comment: **2015-11-30** I'm back with this problem. First I switched from Tomcat to JBoss EAB. There it worked. Now I had to use WebLogic 12c and the behaviour is back again.